Joined Progression (all possible ones)
Complete the last grid and tell me a suitable two-word phrase which answers the question below.



The two-word answer could be:

 square area.

The highlighted dots ...

 ... follow this pattern: The first grid has four dots arranged in a square in the top left corner. Let's say this square has area 1.

 Starting with this grid, each grid has all possible squares of twice the area of the previous grid whose midpoints are highlighted corners of the squares in the previous grid:



 The last grid has two squares of area 8.

The corresponding letters ...

 ... spell doubling. (They are taken by walking through the points of each square clockwise, starting with the leftmost point.)

 So the question is: What keeps doubling? In this case, it's the area of the individual squares that doubles as the series progresses.


Well done! That's the answer I had in mind aswell.
